# Восстановление раздела WIndows 8

Tags: windows, раздел, windows-8, ноутбук

Ноутбук Samsung NP350E5C-S06, Recovery Solution, все дела.Решил заменить вин 8 на вин 7, предполагая, что смогу вернуть 8 с помощью Recovery.На диске 4 раздела восстановления, 1 шифрованный EFI, 1 диск С, 1 диск с данными.Поставил винду на диск C, соответственно отформатировал. Все нормально, но не работает восстановление системы по F4. Что могло пойти не так? Данные должны быть там, диски не тронуты, акронис загрузочный тоже не запускается. Как достать windows8?

Answer (score 1):

При установке что W7, что W8 создается свой диск восстановления по 100 MB.
Немного не понял вашу фразу:

> На диске 4 раздела восстановления

Если это общее количество логических разделов, то почему далее Вы описываете только 3? Если есть действительно 4 раздела по 100 МВ каждый, то откуда столько счастья?
Теоретически W7 должна была затереть диск восстановления W8 (по умолчанию, кажется именно такие действия) - поэтому и не получается восстановится.
Опишите подробнее сложившуюся ситуацию.

Comment: Думается, в "4 раздела восстановления" пропущена запятая и очепятка, итого 4 раздела: восстановления, шифрованный EFI, диск С, диск с данными